# mysql multiprocess - fetch data while writing

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading

I need to log data from sensor as fast as possible.
Therefore I start a process for continuously writing data to MySQL database by a parallel running thread in python.

After I started this thread, I need to frequently fetch some data of the database, which have been inserted of the active thread.

The issue is, that **I can´t get acces to the data while the thread is running**.
after I stop the thread, I can read the data out of the database. I also tried to "commit" the writing every on every row, but it still does not work.

Here is my test-script:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import pooling
import datetime, json, threading


mydb = mysql.connector.pooling.MySQLConnectionPool( pool_size = 3,
                                                    host = "localhost",
                                                    user = "user",
                                                    passwd = "password",
                                                    database = "any"
                                                )

connection = mydb.get_connection()
connection_1 = mydb.get_connection()

my_cursor = connection.cursor()
my_cursor_1 = connection_1.cursor()

def continous_process():
    while True:
        cmd = "INSERT INTO config (config_json, date) VALUES (%s, %s)"
        date = datetime.datetime.now()
        values = (json.dumps("something"), date)
        my_cursor.execute(cmd, values)
        my_cursor.execute("COMMIT")

def get_last_config():
        my_cursor_1.execute("SELECT entry_id FROM config ORDER BY entry_id DESC LIMIT 1")
        print(my_cursor_1.fetchall()[0])

my_thread = threading.Thread(target=continous_process)
my_thread.start()
print(my_thread.is_alive())

while True:
    print(get_last_config())
```

Is it necessary to release the connection by `connection.release()` after each entry?
Im looking forward to a performant solution, which is alsmost "realtime".

Comment: I would try to use nowait as per this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21884769/why-use-nolock-and-nowait-together

Comment: Remember that MySQL is not the only database you can use here, so look at alternatives if you're really pinned on IO.

Comment: which databases you have in mind?
i tried it now with `autocomment = true`, and now i have access to data without release connection. 
additional information: when I use `excecutemany()`, i can insert big datasets quite fast (100k rows with 5x int columns in 5sec). the query itself, i can source out to another thread.