# SQL iterate UPDATE from python list

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql

Do you guys know how to UPDATE a database from a python list without using cur.executemany? Using cur.executemany I have problems in API calls or something. What is another way to solve this below? Thank you!

```
import psycopg2 
conn = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL) # Postgres
cur = conn.cursor()

list_account = [('Bob', 55), ('John', 10)]
cmd_type = ("""
  UPDATE db.table
  SET name = %s
  WHERE age = %s""")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.executemany(cmd_type, list_people)
```

I know below is crazy ugly, but I did that.

```
for i in range(len(list_account)):
  cmd_type = ("""
    UPDATE db.table
    SET name = '{}'
    WHERE age = '{}'""".format(list_account[i][0], list_account[i][1]))

  cur = conn.cursor()
  cur.execute(cmd_type) 
  conn.commit()
```

Comment: you can do execute() and then commit() on the connection. which library do you use?

Comment: not sure what you are using but did that for someone else: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62166481/mysql-multiprocess-fetch-data-while-writing/62167891#62167891 (just look at the insert thread and iterate through your list of variables)
This code uses mysq-connector-python (MySQL native library) and works well. again depends which database and library you use0

Comment: do you commit on the CONNECTION after this code? not familiar with the (EDITED)  last bit

Comment: which database? MySQL? MSSQL?

Comment: which library do you use?

Comment: Postgres Nono. Thank you library psycopg2.
conn = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL)
cur = conn.cursor()

Comment: Warning In its current implementation this method is not faster than executing execute() in a loop. For better performance you can use the functions described in Fast execution helpers. https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.executemany, you ar e aware about this right?

Comment: in your code: list_account = [('Bob', 55), ('John', B)], Why B, (next to john ) not between ""? Is it a class?

Comment: Im not sure man , but the hard coded loop is working. It looks so ugly right, do you have thoughts?

Comment: ok so now it is a 10, not a B

Comment: what IDE do you use? is it jupyter?

Comment: yea. Great job Nono.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215269/discussion-between-nono-london-and-bo-peng).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer but I don't want to edit your code as I don't have Postgres installed yet.

It seems like with the library you use there is no optimization by using executemany(). So can you try the following code, which is just and transalte from what I usually do. I made comments in capitals as a few things do not make necessarly sense (but possible)

```
import psycopg2
DATABASE_URL='db'

conn = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL) # Postgres
#ARE YOU SURE YOU DON'T NEED USERNAME, PASSWORD AND PORT?
cur = conn.cursor()

list_account = [('Bob', 55), ('John', 10)]

#IN YOU UPDATE STATEMENT YOU CALL THE DATABASE NAME: "db", AND THE TABLE 'table'
#ARE YOU SURE ABOUT THIS?
cmd_type = ("""
  UPDATE db.table
  SET name = %s
  WHERE age = %s""")
cur = conn.cursor()
for params in list_account:
    cur.execute(cmd_type, params)
    conn.commit()
```

using [doc link](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.executemany)

does this work?

if it doesn't try this:

```
import psycopg2
DATABASE_URL='db'

conn = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL) # Postgres
#ARE YOU SURE YOU DON'T NEED USERNAME, PASSWORD AND PORT?
cur = conn.cursor()

list_account = [('Bob', 55), ('John', 10)]

#IN YOU UPDATE STATEMENT YOU CALL THE DATABASE NAME: "db", AND THE TABLE 'table'
#ARE YOU SURE ABOUT THIS?
cmd_type = ("""
  UPDATE `table`
  SET name = %s
  WHERE age = %s""")
cur = conn.cursor()
for params in list_account:
    cur.execute(cmd_type, params)
    conn.commit()
```